# Heroku multi region support

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, heroku, heroku-postgres, multi-master-replication

Does Heroku offer multi region support for it's implementation?  I'm specifically interested in a master-master database setup in multiple AWS regions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am looking at the same answer, 4 years later. Here is what I found:

- The only regions Heroku offer is EU / US for the common runtime.
- If you are a Heroku Enterprise client and use Private Spaces, you have access to the following regions: Dublin, Frankfurt, Oregon, Sydney, Tokyo and Virginia. [source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/regions#view-the-list-of-available-regions)

By default, Heroku does NOT provide any multi-AZ support, unless you take the Premium options on PG. From what I see, you cannot choose which region you want the replication to be in. [source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-ha)

Lastly, if you want to setup yourself a multi-az architecture (on PG or any other component), you will have to do it yourself.